# Chai (as promised) match property

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, chai-as-promised

How can I test a property against a regular expression in `chai`? Bonus points: I actually want to test a property of an object returned by a promise using `chai-as-promised` (but I guess if I know the non-promise way `chai-as-promised` should just work the same way).

My function

```
function foo() { 
  return Promise.resolve({ bar: 'baz' }); 
}
```

My test (my idea):

```
// Non-Promise-way
foo().should.match.property('bar', /baz/);    

// Promise-way
foo().should.eventually.match.property('bar', /baz/);
```

(but there is no `match.property`)

Comment: Is this question about the correct way to check for a property or about how to check that property with a regex?

Comment: The combination of it. And I just found out it's `foo().should.eventually.have.property('bar').and.match(/baz/);`. Someone also answered this but then deleted it. I now see I need to update my question though.

Comment: I deleted it because I didn't do a match, but an equal check instead.

Comment: Correct your answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Chai API docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) I derived this:

```
foo().should.have.property('bar').and.match(/baz/);
```

Or for the promise style:

```
foo().should.eventually.have.property('bar').and.match(/baz/);
```